# WordPress has removed the administrator role from all administrator users but only on server

Tags: wordpress

I've run into a problem where my admin users cannot add administrator level users.

Looking into it and debugging the core `get_editable_roles` i've found that the admin user caps (`$user->caps`) have administrator but the user roles (`$user->roles`) doesn't have an administrator value.

This only happens on our server, both staging and production, but is working fine locally. Totally same installation, plugins, database on all three systems.

I've used user role editor to confirm the administrator role is set up. It doesn't show there for me either, I tried adding it and it says it already exists. I've modified the `editable_users` filter to skip removing of the administrator role and it appears again, but it looks fine, everything is checked. Saving it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a plugin, found after extensive troubleshooting. The odd local vs server differences were because of New Relic extensions for monitoring that weren't present locally so there some of the logic in the plugin wasn't run.

I hadn't thought a plugin could do this, expecting core or config issues. But after calling `wp_get_current_user` you are given the global `$current_user` instance, and with that can change the `$current_user->roles` array which could cause unexpected behavior for any other plugins, themes, or the site.